# ValueError while rendering form in template

Tags: python, django, forms

Ok, this is the 3rd day searching a solution to this error, so I'm just going to ask here.

I am aware that there are other questions similar to mine, but apparently all the others have another cause.
This is my setup:
Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.1

My error is this:

`ValueError at /testsel`

`too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

This is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/Projects/Organizacional/organizacional/home/views.py", line 36, in testsel
    return render(request,'home/testsel.html',{ 'form':form })
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 993, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 972, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 397, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 142, in __str__
    return self.as_table()
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 284, in as_table
    errors_on_separate_row=False,
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 202, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 313, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 648, in value_from_datadict
    return getter(name)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 390, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/ricardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1161, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is the function that's being called at views.py:

```
def testsel(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        pass #just testing for now
    else:
        form=SelectTest(Tests.objects.all())
    return render(request,'home/testsel.html',{ 'form':form })
```

This is the form that is defined at forms.py:

```
class SelectTest(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectTest,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        CHOICES=args[0].values('sigla')
        CHOICES=[(s['sigla'],s['sigla'].lower()) for s in CHOICES]
        self.fields['select']=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),choices=CHOICES)
```

This is my template:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }} 
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is Tests that is called at views.py (although I don't think it really matters):

```
class Tests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sigla = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    instruction = models.TextField()
    about = models.TextField()
    nquestions = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    table = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Now, If I change my template to this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.select }}
{% endfor %}
```

it renders with no errors, but the form is not rendered, or appears at 'view source'. If I use only `field` inside the loop, I'm back to 'too many values to unpack'.

I know that I need to pass a list of tuple at choices, and that is what it is being done. I've triple checked it.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to a form is the data to bind it with. You're passing a queryset there, and immediately passing it to the superclass, which is causing the error.

If you want to pass extra data to a form you should always use a keyword argument, and remove it from the kwargs dict before calling super.

```
form=SelectTest(sigla=Tests.objects.all())
```

...

```
class SelectTest(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sigla = kwargs.pop('sigla', None)
        super(SelectTest,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

Note, you should probably use a ModelChoiceField - which accepts a queryset directly - rather than a simple ChoiceField.

Comment: Beaultifull! Thank you very much!